# Strange issue in jQuery ajax in chrome browser

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using ajax function to call one api. that api respond in approx 20 seconds.

```
$.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST', url: "domain.com/request_api", data: param ,
            success: function (response) 
            {
                console.log( response );
            }
        });
```

it is very simple ajax function. the issue when i try to click something else or call another ajax function. that function will wait for the response of this request. one this request is completed. then the other ajax function show response. 
how can make the ajax request independent of each other? in theory they should run in parallel. and each of them should respond  once completed.

Comment: _"the issue when i try to click something else or call another ajax function. that function will wait for the response of this request."_ That should not be occurring. Can you reproduce the issue at stacksnippets or jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: yes in theory i understand. but it seems to be the issue specific on the page i am working. when call is made for the api which is v slow approx 20 other ajax call also just wait for it.i m using private api's which i can use in jsfiddle

Comment: I see one call there... So how is the second one triggered?

Comment: second one is just like this one. jQuery ajax function with a different link to server